# Cortex M0 HardFault_Handler and getting the fault address

Tags: debugging, arm, keil

I'm having a HardFault when executing my program. I've found dozens of ways to get PC's value, but I'm using Keil uVision 5 and none of them has worked.

As far as I know I'm not in a multitasking context, and PSP contains 0xFFFFFFF1, so adding 24 to it would cause overflow.

Here's what I've managed to get working (as in, it compiles and execute):

```
enum { r0, r1, r2, r3, r12, lr, pc, psr};

extern "C" void HardFault_Handler()
{
  uint32_t *stack;
  __ASM volatile("MRS stack, MSP");

  stack += 0x20;

  pc = stack[pc];
  psr = stack[psr];
  __ASM volatile("BKPT #01");   
}
```

Note the "+= 0x20", which is here to compensate for C function stack.

Whenever I read the PC's value, it's 0.
Would anyone have working code for that?

Otherwise, here's how I do it manually:

- Put a breakpoint on HardFault_Handler (the original one)
- When it breaks, look as MSP
- Add 24 to its value.
- Dump memory at that address.
  And there it is, 0x00000000.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few problems with your code

```
uint32_t *stack;
__ASM volatile("MRS stack, MSP");
```

`MRS` supports register destinations only. Your assembler migt be clever enough to transfer it to a temporary register first, but I'd like to see the machine code generated from that.

If you are using some kind of multitasking system, it might use PSP instead of MSP. See the linked code below on how one can distinguish that.

```
pc = stack[pc];
psr = stack[psr];
```

It uses the previous values of `pc` and `psr` as an index. Should be

```
pc = stack[6];
psr = stack[7];
```

> Whenever I read the PC's value, it's 0.

Your program might actually have jumped to address 0 (e.g. through a null function pointer), tried to execute the value found there, which was probably not a valid instruction but the initial SP value from the vector table, and faulted on that. This code

```
void (*f)(void) = 0;
f();
```

does exactly that, I'm seeing 0x00000000 at offset 24.

> Would anyone have working code for that?

[This works for me.](http://www.freertos.org/Debugging-Hard-Faults-On-Cortex-M-Microcontrollers.html) Note the code choosing between psp and msp, and the `__attribute__((naked))` directive. You could try to find some equivalent for your compiler, to prevent the compiler from allocating a stack frame at all.

Comment: Thanks, I added some precision and missing code. My compiler/assembler actually doesn't support "MRS R0, MSP", however the result of my "MRS stack, MSP" is the same. That limits me a lot, it doesn't seem to understand any register. So far I haven't found equivalents to the __attribute__((naked)) that would work with the compiler, but anyway, you confirmed this is overall correct. And thank you very much for the tip of the calling a null pointer, hadn't thought about that, could be a missing callback...

Comment: Based on your answer, I had a look at the value of LR pushed into the stack. It points to a valid location, so I guess that is it, thanks!